# Animate a chart as the user scroll down

Tags: javascript, css

I have a question in CSS3 and JavaScript. I'd like to make those chart bars to animate as the user scroll on those? Right now it's animating 500ms after page load. I would like to start the chart bar animation when the user scroll on it. However, I have no idea how I can detect whether a specific chart is visible by the user.

```js
setTimeout(function start() {

    $('.bar').each(function (i) {
        var $bar = $(this);
        $(this).append('<span class="count"></span>')
        setTimeout(function () {
            $bar.css('width', $bar.attr('data-percent'));
        }, i * 100);
    });

    $('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).parent('.bar').attr('data-percent')
        }, {
            duration: 2000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%');
            }
        });
    });

}, 500)
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400, 400italic|Montserrat:400, 700);
 html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
html {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
q, blockquote {
    quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    content:"";
    content: none;
}
a img {
    border: none;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    color: #333;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    padding: 2%;
}
.wrap {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: .5em 0;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul li {
    line-height: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-size: .85em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    clear: both;
}
ul li:before {
    content:"\2023";
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
}
.bar {
    background: #e74c3c;
    width: 0;
    margin: .25em 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    transition: width 2s, background .2s;
    clear: both;
}
.bar:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background: #ed7669;
}
.bar .label {
    font-size: .75em;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #3d3d3d;
    width: 8em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
.bar .label.light {
    background: #575757;
}
.count {
    position: absolute;
    right: .25em;
    top: .75em;
    padding: .15em;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
     <h1>Animated Bar Graphs</h1>

    <div class="holder">
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="85%"><span class="label">Photoshop</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="75%"><span class="label light">Illustrator</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="65%"><span class="label">Indesign</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="90%"><span class="label light">HTML</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="90%"><span class="label">CSS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="80%"><span class="label light">jQuery</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="85%"><span class="label light">RWD</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="75%"><span class="label">PHP</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="80%"><span class="label light">WordPress</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="70%"><span class="label">SASS/SCSS</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to animate each individual bar or the whole chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.holder').offset().top) {
        ...
    }
});
```

This will call the animation when the `scrollTop` of your `window` object is at the beginning of your cart and thus it ensures, in case your cart is at the very bottom of your page, that the animation is activated at the right point and not too early nor late.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= $('.holder').offset().top) {
        $('.bar').each(function(i) {
            var $bar = $(this);
            $(this).append('<span class="count"></span>')
            setTimeout(function() {
                $bar.css('width', $bar.attr('data-percent'));
            }, i * 100);
        });

        $('.count').each(function() {
            $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
                Counter: $(this).parent('.bar').attr('data-percent')
            }, {
                duration: 2000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function(now) {
                    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%');
                }
            });
        });
    }
})
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400, 400italic|Montserrat:400, 700);
 html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
html {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
caption, th, td {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
q, blockquote {
    quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
    content:"";
    content: none;
}
a img {
    border: none;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    color: #333;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    padding: 2%;
}
.wrap {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h1 {
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: .5em 0;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul li {
    line-height: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-size: .85em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    clear: both;
}
ul li:before {
    content:"\2023";
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
}
.bar {
    background: #e74c3c;
    width: 0;
    margin: .25em 0;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    transition: width 2s, background .2s;
    clear: both;
}
.bar:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background: #ed7669;
}
.bar .label {
    font-size: .75em;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #3d3d3d;
    width: 8em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
.bar .label.light {
    background: #575757;
}
.count {
    position: absolute;
    right: .25em;
    top: .75em;
    padding: .15em;
    font-size: .75em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:"Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
     <h1>Animated Bar Graphs</h1>

    <div class="holder">
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="85%"><span class="label">Photoshop</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="75%"><span class="label light">Illustrator</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="65%"><span class="label">Indesign</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="90%"><span class="label light">HTML</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="90%"><span class="label">CSS</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="80%"><span class="label light">jQuery</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="85%"><span class="label light">RWD</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="75%"><span class="label">PHP</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="80%"><span class="label light">WordPress</span>
        </div>
        <div class="bar cf" data-percent="70%"><span class="label">SASS/SCSS</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but is one problem look on your 'if' this code is always starting and al,l time are creating .count. Percents all time are counting